# Problema para declarar directiva en Formulario modal sin .module.ts

Tags: angular7, ngx-admin

Estoy con un proyecto en Angular 7. Tengo varios forms y en los campos que son solo digitos y/o importes utilizo esta directiva onlyDigits (https://github.com/changhuixu/ngx-digit-only) y funciona muy bien.
Tal cual dice la documentacion cuando tengo un .html que pertence a un modulo, la utilizo de esta forma:

En el .module.ts declaro de esta forma:

```
import { DigitOnlyModule } from '@uiowa/digit-only';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    DigitOnlyModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

Y en el formulario html que necesito usarla lo hago de esta forma:

```
<input type="text" digitOnly />
```

Nada del otro mundo y tal cual como dice la documentacion. El PROBLEMA es que tengo un par de formularios (modales) que son genéricos y no estan definidos como modulos entonces no funciona el digitOnly (tampoco tira error ni nada...solo no funciona). Este es un ejemplo de uno de ellos y donde uso el digitOnly pero no me funciona:

```
<form class="form" role="form" [formGroup]="form">
<fieldset>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <span>{{ modalHeader }}</span>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class=" form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nim a portar</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" digitOnly maxlength="4" class="form-control" placeholder="Prefijo (sin 0)" [formControl]="form.controls['pref']" [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': form.controls['pref'].hasError('required') && form.controls['pref'].touched}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <input type="text" digitOnly maxlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Número (sin 15)" [formControl]="form.controls['nim']" [ngClass]="{'form-control-danger': form.controls['nim'].hasError('required') && form.controls['nim'].touched}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['pref'].hasError('required') && form.controls['pref'].touched">¡El código de área del Nim a portar es requerido!</div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['pref'].hasError('minlength') && form.controls['pref'].touched">¡El código de área del Nim a portar debe contener al menos 2 dígitos!</div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['pref'].hasError('pattern') && form.controls['pref'].touched">¡El código de área del Nim a portar no tiene el formato correcto!</div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['nim'].hasError('required') && form.controls['nim'].touched">¡El número del Nim a portar es requerido!</div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.controls['nim'].hasError('pattern') && form.controls['nim'].touched">¡El número del Nim a portar no tiene el formato correcto!</div>
                <div style="color:red" class="m-1 form-control-feedback" *ngIf="form.hasError('phoneLength')">¡El número del Nim a portar (Cód área + número) no tiene la longitud correcta!</div>
            </div>
            <button class="col-sm-1 btn btn-edit-claro btn-copy" (click)="copyText(formNim.value.area + formNim.value.num)"><i class="far fa-copy" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div class=" form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Empresa orig.</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['operator']">
                    <option [value]="null" hidden>Seleccione la empresa de origen </option>
                    <option [value]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of modalOperators">{{i.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="market" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mercado orig.</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['market']">
                    <option [value]="null" hidden>Seleccione el mercado origen</option>
                    <option [value]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of modalMarkets">{{i.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row with-space left-panel-form">
            <div class="col-sm-12 title-form">
                <span>Gestión plan nuevo</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Mercado dest.</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['markettarget']"
                    (change)="changeMarketTarget($event.target.value)">
                    <option [value]="null" hidden>Seleccione el mercado destino </option>
                    <option [value]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of modalMarkets">{{i.name}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="payment" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Abono elegido</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <select class="form-control" [formControl]="form.controls['payment']">
                    <option [value]="null" hidden>Seleccione el abono del plan </option>
                    <option [value]="i.id" *ngFor="let i of payments">{{i.description}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-claro" (click)="closeModal()">Cerrar</button>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-claro" (click)="onSaveContinue()">Agregar y
            Limpiar</button>
        <button type="button" [disabled]="!form.valid" class="btn btn-claro" (click)="onSaveClose()">Agregar y
            Cerrar</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

y el .component.ts de dicho formulario:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbActiveModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { ErrorMessageService } from '../error-message/error-message.service';
import { AditionalNimVo } from '../../services/vos/AditionalNimVo';
import { WSRESTCatalog } from '../../services/catalog.service';

@Component({
selector: 'ngx-aditionalnim',
templateUrl: './aditional-nim.component.html',
styleUrls: ['../../app.component.scss'],
})
    export class AditionalNimComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() passEntry: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

form: FormGroup;
modalHeader: string;
modalOperation: number;
modalObject: any;
modalOperators;
modalMarkets;
payments;

constructor(private activeModal: NgbActiveModal,
            private fb: FormBuilder,
            private catalogService: WSRESTCatalog,
            private errorService: ErrorMessageService,
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
        pref: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2),
            Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*$')])),
        nim: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[1-9][0-9]*$')])),
        operator: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        market: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        markettarget: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
        payment: new FormControl(null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])),
    }, { validator: this.checkLenghtTogether });
}

checkLenghtTogether(group: FormGroup): any {

    if (group) {
        const area = group.get('pref').value;
        const num = group.get('nim').value;
        if (area && num && (area.length + num.length) !== 10)
        return {phoneLength: true};
    }

    return null;
}

closeModal(): void {
    this.activeModal.dismiss();
}

changeMarketTarget(value) {
    if (value) {
        this.catalogService.getAllActivePayments(value).subscribe(
            data => {
                this.payments = data['body'];
            },
            error => {
                this.errorService.showError('Aviso Importante',
                    error['error']['description']);
            },
        );
    }
}

onSaveContinue() {
    const aditional = this.fillAditional(
        this.form.value.pref,
        this.form.value.nim,
        this.form.value.operator,
        this.form.value.market,
        this.form.value.markettarget,
        this.form.value.payment);

    this.passEntry.emit(aditional);

    this.form.reset();
}

onSaveClose() {
    const aditional = this.fillAditional(
        this.form.value.pref,
        this.form.value.nim,
        this.form.value.operator,
        this.form.value.market,
        this.form.value.markettarget,
        this.form.value.payment);

    this.passEntry.emit(aditional);

    this.activeModal.dismiss();
}

private fillAditional(nim: string, phone: string,
            operatorid: number, marketid: number, markettargetid: number,
            paymentid: number): AditionalNimVo {
    const aditional = new AditionalNimVo();
    aditional.phone = phone;
    aditional.pref = nim;
    aditional.operatorid = operatorid;
    aditional.operator = this.modalOperators.find(x => Number(x.id) === Number(operatorid))['name'];
    aditional.marketid = marketid;
    aditional.market = this.modalMarkets.find(x => Number(x.id) === Number(marketid))['name'];
    aditional.markettargetid = markettargetid;
    aditional.markettarget = this.modalMarkets.find(x => Number(x.id) === Number(markettargetid))['name'];
    aditional.paymentid = paymentid;
    const pay = this.payments.find(x => Number(x.id) === Number(paymentid));
    aditional.payment = pay['description'];

    return aditional;
}
```

}

Como les comentaba anteriormente, aqui no me funciona el digitOnly porque no tengo un .module.ts para declararlo. Probé declarandoló en el app.module.ts pero tampoco funcionó. Alguien que me pueda orientar como usarlo o que le haya pasado lo mismo con alguna otra directiva en este tipo de formularios???. Gracias al menos por leerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

en este tipo de caso, como no tengo un .module.ts para declarar el digitOnly, lo tuve que resolver de una forma mas "casera" y fue armando un funcion respondiendo al evento html keypress. Les dejo la solucion para esto por si a alguno le sirve:

En el html:

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="numberOnly($event)" maxlength="4" class="form-control" id="pref" placeholder="Prefijo (sin 0)" [formControl]="form.controls['pref']">
```

Y en el .component.ts:

```
numberOnly(event): boolean {
    const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```